# Kibana is ending up with error code of 503

Tags: kibana-6

When i am using curl command to check the kibana status , it says:

```
curl -I http://localhost:5601/status

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

retry-after: 30

content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

cache-control: no-cache

content-length: 30

Date: Sat, 04 May 2019 12:50:18 GMT

Connection: keep-alive

Kibana.YML file

cat /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

elasticsearch.url: "http://10.0.1.41:9200"

server.port: 5601

server.host: "localhost"

server.ssl.enabled: false

logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
```

Can someone help me here to solve the 503 error?

Tried to get change the Kibana.yml but noluck

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Amazon Linux AMI, which has been resolved now.